# Set a % width for a link styled as button regardles of its text lenght

Tags: html, css

I think the titles says it all. I want to style a css link to look like a button. I have this code here:

```
    .botsup {
  padding:5px;
background:#ffae00; /*fallback for browsers that don't support gradients*/
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
border:4px outset #dad9d8;

  border: 3px solid #999;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 20px;
/*give the button a drop shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
  text-decoration:none;

display: block;
width: 82%;
line-height: 190%;
font-family: "Arial";
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size: 98.5%;
color: gray;


}
```

It works fine, but I want to set the button width despite of its text length, and I want to do it by using % insted of px. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there is.

Set:

```
display:inline-block;
```

and remove

```
width: 82%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jd5h/6/

New css:

```
.botsup {
padding:5px;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 190%;
font-family: "Arial";
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 98.5%;
color: gray;
background: #ffae00;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae00, #d67600);
border:4px outset #dad9d8;
border: 3px solid #999;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 1px 6px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: this will do i think ;)

Comment: yeah, I wanted to give the same answer you did :P so I think you read it right.

Comment: @user3261537 Why would you want to set width? You can set a max-width or min-width - with a fixed width you will have same behavior as before.

Comment: @user3261537 But you already did that in your first example in the question??

Comment: In the question example the width depends on the text-length

Comment: @user3261537 Not really - in the question example the width depends on the width of the element that is the parent of the link button. Your button will always be 82% of the parent. Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5jd5h/7/ - first two buttons use your code last one uses mine.